# Keeping the program on the main loop

Tags: c++

I've a simple program which does multiple conversions, but breaks out of the loop after every operation. How can tweak the program to return to the main loop after each function finishes execution.

```
#include <iostream>
#define TRUE 1

using namespace std;

int main(){

    char *str = new char[25];

    cout<< "What do you want to convert?" <<endl;
    cin>> str;

    while (TRUE){


        if (strcasecmp(str, "TEMPERATURE") == 0)
        {
            convert_temp(str);
        }
        if (strcasecmp(str, "WEIGHT") == 0)
        {
            convert_weight(str);
        }
        if (strcasecmp(str, "DISTANCE") == 0)
        {
            convert_distance(str);
        }

    }
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}

void convert_temp(char* str){

        cout<< "Press 1 for C to F | Press 2 for F to C" <<endl;
            int temp = 0;
            cin >> temp;
            if(temp == 1){
                int c, f = 0;
                cout<< "Enter the value" <<endl;
                cin >> c;
                f = (9/5)*c - 32;
                cout<< "The temperature is " << f << " degree F"<< endl;
            }else if (temp == 2){
                int c, f = 0;
                cout << "Enter the value"<<endl;
                cin >> f;
                c = (f-32)*(5/9);
                cout << "The temperature is " << c <<  " degree C"<<endl;
            }
            break;

}
void convert_weight(char* str){
    cout<< "Press 1 for POUNDS to KGS | Press 2 for KGS to POUNDS" <<endl;
            int temp = 0;
            cin >> temp;
            if(temp == 1){
                int k, p = 0;
                cout<< "Enter the value" <<endl;
                cin >> p;
                k = p/2.2046;
                cout<< "Your weight is " << k << " Kgs"<< endl;
            }else if (temp == 2){
                int k, p = 0;
                cout << "Enter the value"<<endl;
                cin >> k;
                p = k*2.2046;
                cout << "Your weight is " << p <<  " Pounds"<<endl;
            }
            break;
}

void convert_distance(char* str){
        cout<< "Press 1 for KM to MILES | Press 2 for MILES to KM" <<endl;
            int temp = 0;
            cin >> temp;
            if(temp == 1){
                int k, m = 0;
                cout<< "Enter the value" <<endl;
                cin >> k;
                m = 32*k;
                cout<< "The distance is " << k << " Miles"<< endl;
            }else if (temp == 2){
                int k, m = 0;
                cout << "Enter the value"<<endl;
                cin >> m;
                k = 10*m;
                cout << "The distance is " << k <<  " Kms"<<endl;
            }
            break;
}
```

My questions is thus how can I replace the break statement with a call to the main loop.I dont want to run the functions in a sequence inserting all of them into the main loop.

Comment: Just move the `while` statement up a couple of lines.

Comment: Why are you defining TRUE, if you are using C++?

Answer (score 4):

Your code should look more like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

void convert_temp();
// Other prototypes elided

int main() {

    std::string str;

    for(;;) { // I use this in my coding standard to mean 'forever' instead of while(true)

        std::cout << "What do you want to convert?" << std::endl;
        std::cin >> str;

        if (str == "TEMPERATURE") {
            convert_temp();
        }
        if (str == "WEIGHT") {
            convert_weight();
        }
        if (str == "DISTANCE") {
            convert_distance();
        }
        if (str == "EXIT") {
            break;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}

void convert_temp() {

    std::cout << "Press 1 for C to F | Press 2 for F to C" << std::endl;
    int temp = 0;
    std::cin >> temp;
    std::cout << "Enter the value" << std::endl;
    int c, f = 0;
    if (temp == 1) {
        cin >> c;
        f = (9/5)*c - 32;
        std::cout << "The temperature is " << f << " degree F" << std::endl;
    } else if (temp == 2) {
        std::cin >> f;
        c = (f-32)*(5/9);
        std::cout << "The temperature is " << c <<  " degree C" << std::endl;
    }
}

// Other function definitions elided
```

Note that being C++ I have used a `std::string` for the input of the main selection.

The `main()` function now loops round asking 'What do you want to convert?' each time.

This parameter is no longer passed to any of the functions as they know what they are doing and don't need to use the value.

The example `convert_temp()` function has been simplified slightly and the `break;` has been removed as this does nothing in such an ordinary function.

Also note how entering 'EXIT' exits the program.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `exit(0);` to exit the whole program. (Breaking the loop will lead to the shutting down of the process anyway)

Comment: :-( functions don't always need `return`, they often exit by default.

Comment: @quamrana Well the OP can use it when s\he wants the functions to return. By the way I think you didn't got the question. (Me too maybe) I think it's to get out of the functions and return to the main loop.

Comment: So what is it that you think stops the functions returning, given the code the OP has supplied?

Comment: @quamrana I am more than confused, how the main loop breaks here?

Comment: That is another problem which I have also addressed in my answer.

Comment: @quamrana: Not really; you just dumped a replacement program with no explanation.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need for the break statements in your code if you wish to continue with the main loop. [Break means exit from the current control directive](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/control/) (for/switch). You could replace the break statements with `continue;`, but in this case that would be equivalent to not having the continue statement.